# Are questions about Flatpak packaging more appropriate on Stack Overflow or Unix Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about how to best acquire a certain build system in a Flatpak build manifest that is to be used on Flathub.

More specifically,

> I would like to know how to best build a project using the Ant build system as a Flatpak for Flathub.

Where is this best asked?

I'm thinking either Stack Overflow or Unix Stack Exchange, but I'm unsure which is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I would say "neither".

The premise of the question is that you're seeking documentation on how to use Ant to build Flatpaks.  Just on that premise alone, you want us to link you to the documentation (e.g. [here](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/first-build.html)) to showcase how to build Flatpaks.

The time to ask a question would be if you are having trouble with the assembly of it, and have something explicit that we can point at to help troubleshoot.

Because we wouldn't know what your Ant build is doing or why it would be failing or fundamentally **what you yourself have attempted**, it's not worth asking this since you'd effectively be asking us a whole lot more than what you probably intend to.

Comment: >  Just on that premise alone, you want us to link you to the documentation

Can you find anything about Ant there? I have built Flatpaks before, but I'm not sure what the best way of getting Ant as part of the build system is.